# Inserting an image to .docx file by using apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I inserted an image to .docx file by using Apache POI.But When I open the created word file then its showing me the error "the document file can not be opened because there is some problem with the contents." Although I can see the image in the created word file.Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: What code did you try? Can POI read the file fine? Do all versions of Word complain?

Comment: I tried run.addPicture() method.Picture copied to .docx file successfully.But when I opne the .docx file it shows message document contains unreadable content and image is displayed as cross symbol.All versions of word showing the same message

Comment: feb 2016, problem persists. A possibile, partial, solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745466/insert-picture-in-word-document