# Copy pictures to word document

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can someone please tell me how to copy a picture to a word document using java. Ive tried a code but i keep getting an error saying that the document contents are in error. Please help.Thanks a bunch in advance!!

Comment: have you checked this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745466/insert-picture-in-word-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745466/insert-picture-in-word-document)?

Comment: Yeah I saw this code. And I'm getting the exact same error in word 2010. "the document file can not be opened because there is some problem with the contents." And I dont see a solution to this problem in the comments :(

Answer (score 1):

In principle this is pretty simple since you can simply use `XWPFRun.addPicture` to add a picture to a XWPFRun.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordWithImage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum....");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  String imgFile="Koala.png";
  XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(100));

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("...Lorem ipsum....");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum....");

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("test.docx"));

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex.. This code works perfectly in windows 2013. But I'm getting an error in word 2010.the error is the document file cannot be opened because there is some problem with the contents.

Comment: What apache poi version are you using? My is version poi-3.14. Works for me for opening in Word 2007, Word 2016, Openoffice 4.1.2 Writer and Libreoffice 5.1.4 Writer. So I am pretty sure there should not be a problem. Maybe the picture you are using is the problem? Try another? Try manually insert the picture in Word 2010 GUI first?

Comment: I'm using 3.10. And 3.14. Tried it in 2010. Didn't work.. I'm able to manually insert the picture but!!.  I did a little research and think maybe we might have to create our own xwpfdocument. Donno if I'm right just sharing what I found.